# How to output array to string for using in mysql where IN prepared statement

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I need to implode an array into a string that looks like this.

`"2","3"`

That I can place inside my query

```
    select * from example 
    where id IN ()
```

I've imploded the array and it gives me the string

```
`"2,3" `
```

which doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my query with query builder

```
$package_id = [
   0 => 2,
   1 => 3
];
 $query = "SELECT
            MIN(`prices`.`amount`) as `low_price`,
            MAX(`prices`.`amount`) as `high_price`,
            `packages`.`id` as `package_id`,
            `packages`.`order` as `package_order`,
            `packages`.`label` as `package_name`,
            `packages`.`description` as `package_description`,
            `packages`.`interval` as `package_interval`
            from `packages`
            inner join `prices` on `prices`.`package_id` = `packages`.`id`
            where `packages`.`id` IN (:chosen_package_id)
            group by `package_id`
            order by `packages`.`id` asc
        ";


        $prices = DB::select($query, [
            'chosen_package_id' => $package_id,
        ]);
```

Comment: Or, you could leave it as an array, count the elements, put placeholders `?` into your query instead and pass the array as parameters?

Comment: I'd rather stay consistent with the code base. Non of the other queries do that in this project. If I hard code "2","3" it works just need to know how to get that from array

Comment: what does your array look like?

Comment: It's right above the query. package_id

Comment: `$parameters = "\"" . implode("\",\"",$package_id) . "\"";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236259/discussion-between-erik-and-eric-evans).

Comment: You should probably consider using the method illustrated in the manual with [`PDOStatement::exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) example 5 specifically